# Cauchy sequences in homeomorphic spaces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

If two metric spaces are homeomorphic then out, we can say convergent sequences are 'similar' in nature , Could we comment on the nature of cauchy sequences in homeomorphic metric spaces?

For instance

The space of natural numbers with usual metric $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{M} = \{\frac{1}{n} | n\in \mathbb{N}  , n\geq1\}$ are homeomorphic with the map $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

In both spaces convergent sequences are eventually constant sequences, but in $\mathbb{N}$ all cauchy sequences are eventually constant sequences hence convergent, but in $\mathbb{M}$ consider the sequence $x_n = 1/n , n\geq1$ this sequence is cauchy but not convergent to any point in $\mathbb{M}$.

Comment: A sufficent condition would be for the homeomorphism to be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski for what would this condition be sufficient ??

Comment: For Cauchy sequences to be transformed into Cauchy sequences and hence for preserving completeness. Therefore one can say that homeomorphisms do not neccessarily preserve completeness, i.e. that the completeness can not always be deduced by looking only at the topology of a metric space, but that it depends on the chosen distance.

Comment: excellent insight thanks